# Unable to use mysqli::__construct if contained in another object?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have created two files : 
 1. databaseconnect.php
 2. checklogin.php

**databaseconnect.php :**

```
class DatabaseConnection{
public $connected;
public $connection;

public function __construct($host="localhost", $username="abc", $password="def", $dbname="ghi") {
    $tbl_name="login"; // Table name 
    $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_error){
        $this->connected=false;
    }
    else{
        $this->connected=true;
    }
}
}
```

**checklogin.php :**

```
<?php
include 'databaseconnect.php';
if($_POST){
$db = new DatabaseConnection;
if($db->connected){
    //code flow enters here
    $tbl_name = "login";
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
    $myusername = htmlspecialchars($myusername);
    $mypassword = htmlspecialchars($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT user_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id='$myusername' or primary_mail='$myusername'";
    if($result=$db->connection->query($sql)){
    //do something
    //not coming in this loop
    }
}
?>
```

I am getting error in line

```
if($result=$db->connection->query($sql)){
```

What could be the error and what is the proper syntax of using it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you putting your MySQLi in another class?

Comment: @ajtrichards So that I can simply create a object of DatabaseConnection rather than using mysqli::__construct in every file where I need to get access to database and also as the scope goes off, destructor will be called which I have not written here to close the connection.

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: @Zagor23 Unable to enter into if-loop.
Don't know the error.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this. `htmlspecialchars` is **NOT** a database escaping method, it's only supposed to be used when rendering HTML results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$mysqli` in your file **databaseconnect.php** is not defined.

Because you are opening your connection with `$this->connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);`, the connection will be stored in `$this->connection` instead of `$mysql`. So you would replace this:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error){
   $this->connected=false;
}
```

With this:

```
if ($this->connection->connect_error){
   $this->connected=false;
}
```

Secondly, instead of doing your query with `$db->connection->query($sql)`, why not just create a `query()` method in **databaseconnect.php** and call it from there? It makes your code cleaner.

databaseconnect.php:

```
public function query ($sql)
{
   return $this->connection->query ($sql);
}
```

checklogin.php:

```
$sql="SELECT user_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id='$myusername' or primary_mail='$myusername'";
if($result=$db->query($sql)){
   //do something
}
```

And if you are debugging why your query does not execute, you can add a debugging text to databaseconnect.php:

```
public function query ($sql)
{
   return $this->connection->query ($sql) or die ("MySQLi error: '" . $this->connection->error . "' for query: {$sql}");
}
```

Comment: Thank, it helped but it throws an error saying :
No database selected
But I have already given the database name in mysqli::__construct

Comment: Removed database name from mysqli::__construct and added databasename in Select query.This solved the problem.

Comment: The variable you used for the argument does not match the variable you use for connection. You are using `$dbname` as the fourth argument to **databaseconnect.php**'s `__construct()`, but end up using `$db_name` when opening your connection (note the extra underscore).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on MySQLi but:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error){
   $this->connected=false;
}
```

This looks wrong, try this to get the error properly:

```
if ($this->connection->connect_error){
    die('Connect Error: ' . $this->connection->connect_error);
}
else{
    $this->connected=true;
}
```

Comment: yeah, true. But still that doesn't solves the problem

Comment: True, but it means you can handle the error as $this->connected would be false.

Comment: True, will change this. But why I am not able to use $db->connection->query($sql)

Comment: If you change this and handle the error correctly, you should be able to find out why. Echo out connect_error maybe? I've updated my answer, see above.